# CherryPy + Werkzeug Debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, cherrypy, werkzeug

I was comparing CherryPy and Flask when I ran into the [Werkzeug Debugger](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/debug/), which I really like. What wonders me:

Is it possible to integrate Werkzeug's debugger into CherryPy? If so: how?

When I tried to integrate it myself, I got the console working (`/console`), but not the exception handler.

**EDIT:**
Seems like CherryPy catches the errors and handles them, before Werkzeug gets them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my edit I described that CherryPy catches the errors. In the config `throw_errors` can be set to `True`. For me, setting `cherrypy._cprequest.Request.throw_errors = True` did this. The whole code is:

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy import wsgiserver

from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication

class Root(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World :)"

    @cherrypy.expose
    def page(self):
        # Error:
        return self.self.self.pas

cherrypy._cprequest.Request.throw_errors = True

app = cherrypy.Application(Root(), script_name=None, config=None)
app = DebuggedApplication(app, evalex=True)

d = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({'/': app})
server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), d)
try:
    server.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop()
```

I'm sure, there are better ways to do it, but I'm a newbie concerning CherryPy and this hack worked for me.

Comment: Just for the record I wrote a [post](http://blog.joel.mx/post/debugging-cherrypy-applications-with-werkzeug) related to this question.